# Query works in Access but not in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-workbench

I'm new to databases, I started my project in Access but I was told to do it MySQL instead. So I'm transfering what I did in Access to MySQL but none of my queries are working in MySQL, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Any advice?

Oh, btw, I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2 on Windows.

```
SELECT S.Sname, S.SSN, Count(E.CourseNumber) AS CountOfCourseNumber
FROM Student AS S, Enrollment AS E
WHERE S.SSN=E.SSN
GROUP BY S.Sname, S.SSN
```

This is the first one for now,  It had the correct results in Access but in MySQL it's saying results 0.

Comment: Is the table definition in your MS Access and mysql the same? Also the data are all the same?

Comment: yea the data and primary keys are all the same, and ive done like a simple quary like (select name from student) and that works perfectly, do i have to some how manual connect the tables or something? @rcs

Comment: how about the enrollment table data? can you post your data here?

Comment: okay so for some reason when i connected to the mysql server all my tables information got transfer execpt enrollments table info filled it up an it works. thanks @rcs for directing me to look at that table didnt think of that lmao

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT S.Sname, S.SSN, Count(E.CourseNumber) AS CountOfCourseNumber
FROM Student S LEFT JOIN Enrollment E
ON S.SSN=E.SSN
GROUP BY S.Sname, S.SSN
```

If not, you'd have to look at the underlying data.